# top left vs. upper left, lower-left vs bottom left, which are more common?

Tags: word-choice

Top left vs. upper left, lower-left vs bottom left, which are more common? Or all of the combinations are right to use in any text?

Comment: It depends on the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the context and formality of the conversation, however both can be correct. For example:

> "There is a crack in the top-left of my phone screen"

or

> "If you look at the upper-left window of that building, you will see my apartment"